# Is there a better way to write this specific query?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT (res.phone_number_count + res.computer_count) AS user_count FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phone_number_id) AS phone_number_count, COUNT(DISTINCT computer_id) AS computer_count
    FROM opinions
    WHERE case_id = 1
) AS res;
```

I am trying to get count of both the unique phone_number_ids and computer_ids.

Comment: Questions about improving code that you wrote and that works belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks. Wasn't aware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT phone_number_id) + COUNT(DISTINCT computer_id) AS user_count
FROM opinions
WHERE case_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks! And now I'm ashamed. I need to pay tribute to the developer god for this one.

Comment: @Waffles, don't worry about it - happens to the best of us! Glad you fixed it.